# Issue with digitally signed XML inside SOAP message in Java

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have the following Issue:

I'm making an application that sends an already digitally signed XML certificate to an official govt. Webservice.

When I generate the SOAP message, I copy the whole file to a string (I've used several techniques to do this: Guava's File.toString, Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path), and tried it with all relevant encodings (UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1, since the document is in spanish). I use logger to store the content of the soap message *just before* sending it.

The issue is that the webservice gives me an "Invalid signature" answer, but when I copy the soap message from the log, and send it via SoapUI, the webservice accepts the signed certificate.

Here's the code that does the magic:

```
public class SOAPClientSAAJ {

public static void SendMessage(String file, String rscpath) throws Exception {
    // Create SOAP Connection
    SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
    GetCurrentTimeStamp cts = new GetCurrentTimeStamp();
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLog");  
    FileHandler fh;  

    String logfile = rscpath+cts.GetCurrentTimeStamp()+".log";
    try {  

        // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter  
        fh = new FileHandler(logfile);  
        logger.addHandler(fh);
        SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
        fh.setFormatter(formatter);  

    } catch (SecurityException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (IOException e) {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  

    // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
    String url = "http://172.25.1.220:8080/SGPRTWebServices/RecepcionCrt";
    SOAPMessage soapResponse = null;
    SOAPMessage soapmsg = null;
    logger.info(file.substring(file.lastIndexOf(File.separator)));
    soapmsg = createSOAPRequest(file);
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    soapmsg.writeTo(out);
    String msg = new String(out.toByteArray());
    logger.info(msg);
    out = null;
    msg = null;

    try{
    soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapmsg, url);

    SOAPPart sp = soapResponse.getSOAPPart();
    SOAPEnvelope se = sp.getEnvelope();
    SOAPBody sb = se.getBody();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    soapResponse.writeTo(out2);
    msg = new String(out2.toByteArray());
    logger.info(msg);

    }catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.info(ex.toString());
    }
    soapConnection.close();
}

private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest(String confFilePath) throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String serverURI = "http://recepcionCrt.ws.sgprt.mtt.cl/";

    Path pat =Paths.get(confFilePath);
    Charset charset = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1;

    String texto = "<![CDATA[";
    File fl = pat.toFile();
    String content =  Files.toString(fl, charset);
    texto = texto + content +"]]>";

    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.setEncodingStyle("UTF-8");
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    soapBody.addNamespaceDeclaration("ns2", serverURI);
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement ("recepcionCRT","ns2");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement ("arg0");

    soapBodyElem1.addTextNode(texto);
    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI  + "recepcionCRT");
    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    return soapMessage;
}
}
```

Here:[can you check some files](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1M7v6OL9MOIdkV4YW9YUk4tRXc&usp=sharing) like the wsdl, a valid certificate and a valid soap message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the problem was in the communication process. I had to use the importws tool from the jdk to load the interfaces and clases to comunicate with the provider. Once I did that, the message was recieved correctly and the signature verified.